# Syntax for chaining mongoose promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I am relatively new to using Promises and MongoDB / Mongoose, and am trying to chain a flow through several database queries into an efficient and reliable function.

I want to know if my final function is a good and reliable way of achieving what I want, or if there are any issues or any improvements that can be made.

The process is as follows:

1) Check whether or not the user already exists

```
usersSchema.findOne({
    email: email
}).then(res => {
    if(res==null){
        // user does not exist
    }
}).catch(err => {});
```

2) Add the new user to the database

```
var new_user = new usersSchema({ email: email });
new_user.save().then(res => {
    // new user id is res._id
}).catch(err => {});
```

3) Assign a free promotional code to the user

```
codeSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
    used: false,
    user_id: true
},{
    used: true,
    user_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(res._id)
}).then(res => {
    // user's code is res.code
}).catch(err => {});
```

Obviously, each query needs to execute in sequence, so after a lot of research and experimentation into how to do this I have combined the queries into the following function, which seems to be working fine so far:

```
function signup(email){
    // check email isn't already signed up
    return usersSchema.findOne({
        email: email
    }).then(res => {
        if(res==null){
            // add to schema
            var new_user = new usersSchema({ email: email });
            // insert new user
            return new_user.save().then(res => {
                var result = parse_result(res);
                // assign a code
                return codesSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
                    used: false,
                    user_id: true
                },{
                    used: true,
                    user_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(result._id),
                });
            });
        }else{
            return 'The user already exists';
        }
    });
}

signup('test@test.com').then(res => {
    console.log('success, your code is '+res.code);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

I'm still trying to get my head around exactly how and why this works - the function is returning a promise, and each nested promise is returning a promise.

My main concerns are that there is a lot of nesting going on (is there perhaps a way to do this by chaining .then() callbacks instead of nesting everything?) and that the nested promises don't appear to have error catching, although as the signup() function itself is a promise this seems to catch all the errors.

Is anyone knowledgeable on the subject able to confirm whether my process looks good and reliable or not? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid indentation-hell, if you return a value from the function passed to a Promise's `.then()`-method, you can chain multiple `.then()` as a neat and tidy pipeline. Note that you can also return a Promise that has pending status, and then next function in line will execute when it has resolved.

```
function signup (email) {
  return usersSchema.findOne({
    email: email
  }).then(res => {
    if (res) throw 'The user already exists'
    var new_user = new usersSchema({ email: email })
    return new_user.save()
  }).then(res => {
    var result = parse_result(res)
    return codesSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
      used: false,
      user_id: true
    },{
      used: true,
      user_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(result._id)
    })
  })
}
```

Even better, if you have the possibility to use `async/await` (Node v7.6 or above), your code can look like normal blocking code:

```
async function signup (email) {
  let user = await usersSchema.findOne({ email: email })
  if (user) throw 'The user already exists'
  let new_user = await new usersSchema({ email: email }).save()
  let result = parse_result(new_user)
  return codesSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
    used: false,
    user_id: true
  },{
    used: true,
    user_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(result._id)
  })
}
```

Your original function call code works on both without changes.

Comment: Thanks, these are both great examples! I've had a little play with async/await before, but this helps clarify it's use!

Answer (score 2):

you code can be improve in this way

```
function signup(email){
    // check email isn't already signed up
    return usersSchema.findOne({
        email: email
    }).then(res => {
        if(res==null){            // add to schema
            var new_user = new usersSchema({ email: email });
            // insert new user
            return new_user.save()
        }else{
            return Promise.reject(new Error('The user already exists'));
        }
    })
    .then(res => {
        var result = parse_result(res);
        // assign a code
        return codesSchema.findOneAndUpdate({used: false,user_id: true},{used: true,user_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(result._id),});
    });

}

signup('test@test.com').then(res => {
    console.log('success, your code is '+res.code);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```